# Remove newline in textarea generated by HAML / Form Builder

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have a very simple Rails form.:

```
= form_for @object :remote => true do |form|
   = form.text_area :text, :class => 'form-control'
```

For a new object, with a nil text attribute, this generates:

`<textarea class="form-control" name="object[text]" id="object_text">    </textarea>`

The blank space in that is a newline:

```
(byebug) form.text_area :text, :class => 'form-control'
"<textarea class=\"form-control\" name=\"user_deactivation[reason_text]\" id=\"user_deactivation_reason_text\">\n</textarea>"
```

I strip out the leading and trailing spaces on save, so data wise, its not a big deal, but when the user clicks on this field, it appears indented.

[image]

Relevant software versions:

- Rails 5.02
- haml-4.0.7
- The text area is in a bootstrap 3 dialog

**Why is this newline being generated and how can I stop it?**

Comment: What if you explicitly set the value to `nil` or empty string?

Comment: The value is nil.  Empty string has the same behavior.

Comment: I see, I tried it in slim, guess they don't work the same in every instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the '~' operator, which is like the '=' operator, but automatically runs find_and_preserve on the output.

Like this:

   `= form_for @object :remote => true do |form|
     ~ form.text_area :text, :class => 'form-control'`

Comment: Here is the documentation reference: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-preserve  I had read that, I just saw `~` as `-`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal answer, but it does work.  I would like something better:

```
 = find_and_preserve(form.text_area :text, :class => 'form-control')
```

Can that be automatic?  Is there a way to have the text_area helper not insert a newline?